# attempt to perform arithmetic on field 'x' (a table value) in Lua - not sure about how to resolve

Tags: lua

working in Lua and trying to render a 'projectile' to screen. my projectile class:

```
Projectile = Class{}

function Projectile:init(x, y)
    self.x      = x
    self.y      = y
    self.dx     = math.random(-50, 50)
    self.dy     = math.random(-50, 50)
end

function Projectile:update(dt)

    self.x = self.x + self.dx * dt
    self.y = self.y + self.dy * dt

end

function Projectile:render()
    love.graphics.rectangle('fill', self.x, self.y, 4, 4)
end
```

when my entity enters an 'alert' state, I want that entity to spawn projectiles, so in the EntityAlertPhase state I have this:

```
EntityAlertState = Class{__includes = BaseState}

function EntityAlertState:init(entity)
    self.entity = entity
    self.projectile = self:generateProjectiles()
```

the generateProjectiles function call:

```
function EntityAlertState:generateProjectiles()
    projectile = Projectile {
        x = self.entity.x, 
        y = self.entity.y
    }
    return projectile
end
```

however, this code (I've omitted other code that didn't seem relevant but please lmk if I should include it) causes the titular error.

when I replace this:

```
function EntityAlertState:generateProjectiles()
    projectile = Projectile {
        x = self.entity.x, 
        y = self.entity.y
    }
    return projectile
end
```

with this:

```
function EntityAlertState:generateProjectiles()
    projectile = Projectile {
        x = 50, 
        y = 50
    }
    return projectile
end
```

I still get an error. I believe the cause is somewhere in the Projectile's init function here:

```
function Projectile:init(x, y)
    self.x      = x
    self.y      = y
    self.dx     = math.random(-50, 50)
    self.dy     = math.random(-50, 50)
end
```

because when I sub x and y for ints, I don't get the error anymore and everything works as I expected (of course I need these references to the entity's x and y so I can control where the projectiles go, so this doesn't help me :( )

any responses would be super helpful--also this is my first post so im sorry about any etiquette I've disobeyed!

UPDATE:
so, in the projectile init function, if I do:

```
function Projectile:init(x, y)
    self.x      = x.x
    self.y      = y
    self.dx     = math.random(-50, 50)
    self.dy     = math.random(-50, 50)
end
```

instead of just x?
I don't get the error anymore (assuming I sub y for some integer value). for some reason, y (or even y.y) does not work...and I'm not quite sure how to debug the values that are being passed into the init.

UPDATE2:

since it seems the error might revolve around the Class library, I've included that code here:

```
--[[
Copyright (c) 2010-2013 Matthias Richter

Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

Except as contained in this notice, the name(s) of the above copyright holders
shall not be used in advertising or otherwise to promote the sale, use or
other dealings in this Software without prior written authorization.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
THE SOFTWARE.
]]--

local function include_helper(to, from, seen)
    if from == nil then
        return to
    elseif type(from) ~= 'table' then
        return from
    elseif seen[from] then
        return seen[from]
    end

    seen[from] = to
    for k,v in pairs(from) do
        k = include_helper({}, k, seen) -- keys might also be tables
        if to[k] == nil then
            to[k] = include_helper({}, v, seen)
        end
    end
    return to
end

-- deeply copies `other' into `class'. keys in `other' that are already
-- defined in `class' are omitted
local function include(class, other)
    return include_helper(class, other, {})
end

-- returns a deep copy of `other'
local function clone(other)
    return setmetatable(include({}, other), getmetatable(other))
end

local function new(class)
    -- mixins
    class = class or {}  -- class can be nil
    local inc = class.__includes or {}
    if getmetatable(inc) then inc = {inc} end

    for _, other in ipairs(inc) do
        if type(other) == "string" then
            other = _G[other]
        end
        include(class, other)
    end

    -- class implementation
    class.__index = class
    class.init    = class.init    or class[1] or function() end
    class.include = class.include or include
    class.clone   = class.clone   or clone

    -- constructor call
    return setmetatable(class, {__call = function(c, ...)
        local o = setmetatable({}, c)
        o:init(...)
        return o
    end})
end

-- interface for cross class-system compatibility (see https://github.com/bartbes/Class-Commons).
if class_commons ~= false and not common then
    common = {}
    function common.class(name, prototype, parent)
        return new{__includes = {prototype, parent}}
    end
    function common.instance(class, ...)
        return class(...)
    end
end


-- the module
return setmetatable({new = new, include = include, clone = clone},
    {__call = function(_,...) return new(...) end})
```

Comment: What is `Class`? It's not standard Lua, it's from a library.

Comment: I can't paste the whole code for the Class class here but it's from Matthias Richter and it approximates class functionality that you would expect in other languages.

Comment: Well can you add a link to the explanation of Class?

Comment: im not sure what youre asking--do you want me to explain what a Class is? or how the library works in Lua? do you think the issue might have something to do with how the library instantiates a Class and handles data?

Comment: Well yeah. I have no idea what Class is. Or what it does. And you whole question revolves around Class. It's not part of Lua.

Comment: there's actually a very similar question on here that I just found when I was trying to google documentation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61495184/attempt-to-index-local-def-a-nil-value but it doesn't quite overlap with my question completely. i think if I had a way to debug what I was passing into the init function, or how the init function was handling data via Class, I could probably figure this out - I added the Class code to the question if that is useful?

Answer (score 2):

When you call `Projectile(a, b, c)` for example, it creates a table, associates it with the Projectile class, and then calls `newProjectile:init(a, b, c)` - it passes the same arguments into `init` that you passed into `Projectile`.

When you call `Projectile{x = 50, y = 50}`, you are calling it with one argument, which is a table. Hence your `init` function gets one argument, which is a table.

Comment: your comment discussion with me actually revealed to me what was going on and I solved it right as you answered, so if I hadn't, your response would've certainly revealed to me the issue! thanks so much for taking the time to chat about this. ultimately what I did was in the projectile:init() function I did Projectile:init(def) and then self.x, self.y = def.x, def.y -- but your explanation actually helps me understand on a deeper level. thanks again!

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)